# Splitting Phing build file

Tags: phing

I've got a huge phing build file here. Is there a way to put things like filesets into an external file used by the build.xml? Just need some organisation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [import task](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#ImportTask), which lets you split a build file into multiple files.
You can also look into [property files](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/chapters/appendixes/AppendixF-FileFormats.html#PropertyFileFormat)

[FileLists](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/chapters/appendixes/AppendixD-CoreTypes.html#FileList) also support a `listfile` property which is a text file with one file per line.

[FileSets](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/chapters/appendixes/AppendixD-CoreTypes.html#Fileset) support the `includesfile` and `excludesfile` property which is a text file with a list of patterns.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing now: <import file="filesets.xml"/><import file="filter.xml"/>